# can I debug my web project and wcf project on same vs 2008 instance?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, wcf

I have two projects in my solution 
   1- asp.net web project.
   2- wcf serivce project.
   3- other common projects between two listed above

Current on the local dev machine I have to run two visual studio instance to run both projects in debug mode. That makes the system run out of resources as these projects share some other project in the soultion which are heavy in files.

Is there a way i can hookup the wcf project on a sinlge visual stodio instance and also be able to debug my asp.net web project. ?

I do not want to combine the web and wcf project in to one. Have already considred this option.

thanks for sharing your thoughts in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all the projects in the same solution, set the client (the asp.net app) as the startup project, hit run... you'll be able to debug through from the client to the service and back again.

Answer (score 2):

You can.

Set your web project to use iis.

Use attach to process menu option to select two processes - w3 and service.

Sources for Both processes that you attach to has be in your solution.

Actually you can attach to more than two, in my project i sometimes debug two wcf services and webapplication and js in IE as well